# Exception calling "GetRequestStream" with "0" argument(s): "The remote server returned an error: (504) Gateway Timeout."

Tags: powershell

Server: Windows server 2008 R2
Powershell Version: 3.0

Getting the below error:

```
Exception calling "GetRequestStream" with "0" argument(s): "The remote server 
returned an error: (504) Gateway Timeout."
At C:\Automic\Agents\Powershell\TEMP\JCGLXYHY.TXT.ps1:181 char:1
+ $requestStream = [System.IO.Stream]$request.GetRequestStream()
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebException
```

```
[byte[]]$bytes = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($data)
$request.ContentLength = $bytes.Length
$requestStream = [System.IO.Stream]$request.GetRequestStream()
$requestStream.write($bytes, 0, $bytes.Length)
$requestStream.flush()
$requestStream.close()
try {
    $response = $request.GetResponse()
    $reader = [IO.StreamReader] $response.GetResponseStream()

    #Our response will always be xml except in 404/401 case so cast as such
    $responseXML = $reader.ReadToEnd()
    #$responseXML
    $respXMLDoc = [XML] $responseXML
```

The Same code working on different machine with the same user.

Answer (score 0):

It's *really unclear* what you're asking, but whatever remote endpoint you're trying to interact with is not responding in a timely fashion, and is receiving [HTTP return code 504](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/504).

If this doesn't answer your question, please edit it to make clear what you are asking, and provide sample code of the line that is throwing the error.

Comment: Sorry Mate. Below is the code :````[byte[]]$bytes = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($data)
$request.ContentLength = $bytes.Length
$requestStream = [System.IO.Stream]$request.GetRequestStream()
$requestStream.write($bytes, 0, $bytes.Length)
$requestStream.flush()
$requestStream.close()
try {
    $response = $request.GetResponse()
    $reader = [IO.StreamReader] $response.GetResponseStream()

    $responseXML = $reader.ReadToEnd()
    #$responseXML
    $respXMLDoc = [XML] $responseXML```` but its working on different machine